# I cannot insert into database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can't insert data to MySQL database

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `register`;
    CREATE TABLE `register` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `unique_code` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `mobile` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `address` longtext NOT NULL,
      `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `zipcode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `temp_password` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `image` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
      `phone_verified` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `reg_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `gcm_code` longtext NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I try to register I get this error and no data is added in msql table.

```
INSERT INTO register (
    username,
    mobile,
    password,
    temp_password,
    email,
    status
)
VALUES (
    "user",
    "1234678",
    "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
    "123",
    "admin@admin.com",
    ""
)
Error in query.
```

Here is my MySQL database connection file

```
define('DIRECT_ACCESS', true);
define('HOST','localhost');
define('DATABASE','id9346797_market');
define('USERNAME','idxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('PASSWORD','xxxxxxxx');
define('DB_PREFIX','');
define('SITE_URL', (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/fruitmarket/");
```

i would really appreciate if someone resolves this issue.

**Update:**
I change the previous table to this.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and change mysql database last line

from this

```
define('SITE_URL', (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https" : "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/fruitmarket/");
```

to this

```
define('SITE_URL','http://localhost/fruitmarket/');
```

i am still getting the same error.

here is registeration form

```
<?php  common::user_access_only("admin");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        form_validation::add_validation('username', 'required', 'Registration Name');
         form_validation::add_validation('username', 'no_space', 'Registration Name');
         form_validation::add_validation('mobile', 'required', 'mobile');
        form_validation::add_validation('email', 'required', 'Registration email');
        form_validation::add_validation('email', 'email', 'Registration email not valid');
        form_validation::add_validation('password', 'required', 'Registration Passowrd');
        form_validation::add_validation('password', 'no_space', 'Registration Passowrd');
        if(form_validation::validate_fields())
        {
            $username=common::get_control_value("username");
            $mobile = common::get_control_value("mobile");
            $password=common::get_control_value("password");
            $email=common::get_control_value("email");
            $active = common::get_control_value("status"); 

            $q = new Query();
            $q->insert_into("register",array("username"=>$username,"mobile"=>$mobile,"password"=>md5($password),"temp_password"=>$password,"email"=>$email,"status"=>$active))
            ->show()
            ->run();
            common::set_message(3);
            common::redirect_to(common::get_component_link(array("appuser","list")));

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What if you change your `"` for `'`?

Comment: @RobIII title says MySQL

Comment: what is the error saying exactly?

Comment: The query would work without the `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode (see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7WUhGStrEKA8r1P4aWdN5y/0)). Did you switch the MySQL version last time?

Answer (score 5):

The error message is doing you no favors here, is that the entirety of what MySQL is returning?

You have a large number of fields in your table which are defined as `NOT NULL` and do not have default constraints. But your `INSERT` query does not specify values for all of them. You need to do one (or more) of the following:

- `INSERT` values for all the fields in your table
- Create default constraints for your `NOT NULL` fields
- Redefine the table to allow those fields to be `NULL`

Comment: I agree, I don't think "Error in Query" is the ACTUAL error. So either Umar didn't post the entire message OR whatever system they're using doesn't expose the actual message.

Answer (score 4):

You have a zillion columns in your table that are declared `NOT NULL` without default values, such as `zip_code`and `city`.

You need to do one of three things:

- Insert values for *all* such columns when inserting rows.
- Provide default values in the definition of the table.
- Remove the `NOT NULL` constraint.

I'm not sure which is appropriate for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The status is INT not VARCHAR

```
INSERT INTO register (
    username,
    mobile,
    password,
    temp_password,
    email,
    status
)
VALUES (
    "user",
    "1234678",
    "202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70",
    "123",
    "admin@admin.com",
    0 // not varchar
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The record is not inserted because you have placed NOT NULL for each column which means that in order for a record to be inserted values for all columns should be provided.

If you like to insert a record with only those values set, you have to remove the NOT NULL definition for the other columns.